# adding imageButtons by code

Tags: android, listview, bitmap, android-custom-view, baseadapter

I have a base adapter class  which i use to fill in a listview. Some of the contents are defined in a layout file and i also need to dynamically add in a certain number of image button depending on the int value passed to the base adapter.
The obj is a object that has the int value along with a arrayList of bitmaps;
when i run this code i get more image buttons then the value of obj.value. 
likePre_pics is the name of the arrayList of bitmaps
Can someone please help?

```
      public class News_Feed_BaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

                      @Override
       public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LinearLayout linLayout =
    (LinearLayout)convertView.findViewById(R.id.like_preview_LinearLayout);

      for(int i=0; i< obj.value;i++)
      {
          ImageButton op= new ImageButton(context);

          LayoutParams lpView = new LayoutParams(100, 100);
            //op.setImageBitmap(obj.get(position).likePre_pics.get(i));

             linLayout.addView(op,lpView);

      }

                }
         }
```

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 4
at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
at com.example.foodshootr.News_Feed_BaseAdapter.getView(News_Feed_BaseAdapter.java:96)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)

Comment: Sooo, which is it? You're getting more ImageButtons than expected, or your app is crashing with the above error?

Comment: if i put for(int i=0; i< obj.value;i++) my app  crashes.

Comment: if i put i put for(int i=0; i< 2;i++) i get more imagebuttons. i should have 2 imagebuttons i get 5

Comment: Well, for the second case (excess ImageButtons), you're using the convertView incorrectly. This parameter is a View to be "recycled". You're just adding additional ImageButtons onto a View that already has some set.

Comment: For the other case (app crash), I think we'll have to see some more code. At least your class for obj.

Comment: so how can i dynamically add imagebuttons?

Comment: Instead of adding ImageButtons to the convertView, inflate a new View from your List item layout xml, add them to that View, then return that View as the getView return value.

Comment: You should also investigate how to use a View Holder when implementing ListViews.

Comment: according to @MikeM. you have to inflate your layout and set it to convertview.

Answer (score 0):

As i can see from your code there is two problem,first is IndexOutOfBoundsException. ArrayList IndexOutOfBoundsException only occurs when there is more/less item then you are referring to. 
//op.setImageBitmap(obj.get(position).likePre_pics.get(i));
The line you commented out. You are referring to obj.get(position) where obj has obj.size() number of element.

Next is ImageButton issue since you are not reusing the convertview in an efficient way when you are adding new imagebutton into linLayout of convertview that is why linLayout is showing more then 2 imagebutton.

For example: If you have 20 items in your list that means getView will be called 20 times. As you will find in android documentation convertView is the old view that gets passed for you to reuse and every-time it gets passed to you , you are adding more imagebutton into it. That's why imagebutton problems are occurring.

Take a look into Romain Guy's [World of ListView](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) google i/o presentation if you are interested.